# Android code: how to pass variable in the same activity between methods

Tags: android

I have 4 buttons on my layout. One is the "Correct Answer" and 3 are "WRONG Answers"
I have coded a common method for my WRONG answer, but the code requires me to push the different button names in that piece of code. How do i manage that?

This is my code

```
/* call method for a answer  */
    final Button rredButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RredButton);
    rredButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()      
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupright, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(               
                    popupView,                
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                       
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);     
            Button btnNxtScr = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.nextscreen);             
            btnNxtScr.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){     
                @Override     
                public void onClick(View v) {      
                    Intent myintent1 = new Intent(colorActivity.this,LearningTimeMenu.class);
                    startActivity(myintent1);
                }
            });
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(rredButton, 50, -300);
        }});
```

I tried to do this

```
final Button rblueButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RblueButton);
    rblueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override     
        public void onClick(View arg0) {          
            createWrongPop();      
            }});
```

and define the layout inflator part of the code in the createWrongPop() method; but this line of code
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(rredButton, 50, -330) expects the button ID for each of the 3 buttons.

How do i pass each of the variables to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept parameter in `createWrongPop()` method and pass the view received in the `onClick` method:

```
private void createWrongPop(View view){
    //Your logic here
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 50, -300);
}

final Button rblueButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RblueButton);
rblueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override     
    public void onClick(View arg0) {          
        createWrongPop(arg0);      
    }
});
```